# Privacy Policy for email contact form

Tags: privacy, data-storage, website

I'm building a web page that does not have any sort of registration/login. The only bit of user data is a contact form that allows the user to contact the owners of the page.

This contact form asks for *name* and *email*, which can be personal data, but we will not store this data in any form. Instead, this data is used to send an email to the owners of the page on behalf of the user. So, technically the data is stored in gmail (for example).

Is the Privacy Policy still applicable in this situation? and in which degree? (if there is any kind of degree at all).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is the Privacy Policy still applicable in this situation?

It depends on the law of which country you are subject. But even if the privacy policy was not mandatory, its presence would be recommended. The person using the contact form does not know what is going on with her data after form submitting and it will certainly be well received and it will be reassuring when he or she will know that they are properly secured and processed. The Privacy Policy in this case does not have to be anything long - a few sentences are enough. However, if you know under which law you fall, there might be strict requirements regarding additional information which you need to provide.

Assuming you fall under GDPR (as I see you're located in Spain, EU), you would need to comply with [Article 13 of GDPR](https://gdpr-info.eu/art-13-gdpr/).

See also: [Privacy Policies are Legally Required](https://privacypolicies.com/blog/privacy-policies-legally-required/)

Comment: thanks for the answer. I ended up including a Privacy Policy to explain what was going on with that form. The site is no longer online but I'll review what you poster anyway. Thanks again